# What to use as portfolio diversification measure?

Tags: portfolio-management, risk-management

Suppose that we have a portfolio of $n$ assets.

A perfectly diversified portfolio is one in which each asset has equal weights, i.e. each asset has weight $\frac{1}{n}$. Of course this is usually not the case.

What are some of the ways we can measure how well diversified our portfolio is?

We could measure how far our portfolio is from the equally-weighted portfolio.

This of course will depend on the geometry of the space which is not euclidean since the sum of the weights must be one.

Comment: I **strongly** disagree with the fact that the equally-weighted portfolio is perfectly diversified. If you assume that, then indeed your diversification measure should be the distance to that portfolio. But that would just be wrong in my opinion, and if you choose another measure you should expect the most-diversified portfolio, according to that measure, not to be the equally-weighted portfolio.

Comment: I agree with SRKX but would even go one step further. It does not make a lot of sense (at least to me) to discuss diversification unless you specify a risk measure. Then the perfectly diversified portfolio is one which minimises your particular risk measure.

Comment: True there are many ways to measure diversity. I merely suggest this as one possible way. One draw back with a risk parity approach is that it assumes that your moment estimates are accurate. Perhaps a good risk control policy on top of some risk parity approach is to say that your investment in any asset is between 1% and 5% of total portfolio value. This puts in place a risk control that is independent of your estimates and perhaps sheds some light on why we may want to look at equal weight portfolios.

Comment: I would disagree with this measure because it does not control for number of assets as well. Bu this definition, putting all your eggs in one basket (n=1) will  a 'perfectly' diversified portfolio

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you measure risk by the standard deviation of the portfolio return
$$
\sigma = \sqrt{w^T \Sigma w},
$$
then it is usual to define risk contributions for each asset by
$$
\sigma_i = w_i (\Sigma w)_i/\sigma,
$$
then diversified could mean that these $\sigma_i$ are evenly spread over the assets in the portfolio.

You find this approach and more in this paper by [Meucci](http://www.top1000funds.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Managing-diversification.pdf)

There you also find the variance concentration curve that uses principle components (PCs) of the asset universe and the weighting of the assets to analyze how much the PCs contribute.

Ad good place to read about the application of PCA to portfolio analysis is [Regularization of Portfolio Allocation](http://www.lyxor.com/publications/white-papers/wp/82/) by B. Bruder, N. Gaussel, J-C. Richard and T. Roncalli.

Comment: I've seen this approach before. I always get a little leery when PC analysis is used in risk estimation. PC analysis assumes the existence of zero variance portfolios.

Comment: "PC analysis assumes the existence of zero variance portfolios" - no, it does not. It is rather the opposite ... where do you have this from? Any proof or reference?

Comment: Sorry I miss spoke. What I meant is that PCA allows for the possibility of zero variance assets. This is since PCA can give you a singular covariance matrix which means it is possible a zero on the diagonal. You can also have numerical instability associated with this kind of fitting which can give a near zero diagonal element. I would consider a method that allows for this dangerous.

Comment: @Richard Meucci seems to have moved on past that paper to his one on minimum torsion bets. I've been playing around with it the past couple of days and have found it to be MUCH better.

Comment: @mtiano No, if your assets are linearly independent the PCA will not give you eigenvalues of zero. The covariance matrix will have full rank and all eigenvalues will be bigger than zero. If you have more assets than observation times then you have to use another estimator for the covariance matrix (e.g. shrinkage)

Comment: @John this sound interesting. Do you have a link to that paper too?

Comment: @Richard I can fix you up in the meantime: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2276632

Comment: This answer is a high-level answer toward approaches used by practitioners in quantitative portfolio management. I have worked with firms that sourced data on the components from multiple providers who charge tens of thousands per user to pre-calculate the components periodically and give you a sometimes capable optimization and reporting suite that only works out of the box with their files. The practice might not sync up with the nomenclature in more mathematical literature, because the model providers usually refer to their values as "risk factors." Great question. Important question. And g

Answer (score 4):

[This paper](ftp://economia.unica.it/mattana/Modelli_Mercati_Finanziari/Slides/Lecture_2/CRAA.pdf), Equity Portfolio Diversification by W. Goetzmann and A. Kumar, uses the following diversification measures to measure the diversification of retail investors:

- **Normalized portfolio variance**:
  $$ NV = \frac{\sigma_p ^2}{\bar{\sigma} ^2} $$
- **Sum of Squared Portfolio Weights (SSPW).** Since the weight in the market portfolio is very small diversification could be approximated by the sum of squared portfolio weights:
  $$ SSPW = \sum w_i ^2 $$
- A very crude diversification measure would be the number of assets $N$.

Comment: You could add the title and the name of the authors of the paper, it would be nice for them...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this paper
Measuring Portfolio Diversification
Ulrich Kirchner & Caroline Zunckel
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.4722.pdf

Comment: The 20 word summary of this paper "We propose the negative information entropy of the probability distribution of the final portfolio value
as a suitable diversification measure".

Comment: Could you consider describing why you think this paper contains any nice insights instead of just posting a link? This would improve overall quality of your answer by far=)

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling to quantify and explain diversity for a while and I think I've found something which captures the essence of a portfolio manager's ability to diversify away risk.

Say you have a portfolio where each stock has volatility $\sigma_i$, weight $w_i$, and pairwise correlation $\rho_{ij}$.  Then the portfolio's volatility $\sigma$ can be computed as:

$$\sigma^2 = \underbrace{\sum_i w_i^2 \sigma_i^2}_A + \underbrace{\sum_i\sum_{j \neq i}w_i w_j \sigma_i \sigma_j \rho_{ij}}_{B}$$

Part $A$ of the equation is a pure volatility part, and part $B$ is correlation-dependent part which portfolio managers are forever trying to minimise my choosing stocks which are not too correlated to each other.

Surprisingly, the $A$ part is usually much smaller than the $B$ part.  For example, when I calculate the MSCI AC World's volatility in this way (using a five years of monthly returns of stocks currently in the index), I find $A = 0.01\%$ and $B = 1.04\%$.  When I split my fund's portfolio risks in this manner, I always find $B$ to be much bigger than $A$ (four to ten times bigger).

Since the goal is to minimize $B$, I propose $\sigma^2/A$, or
$$\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum w_i^2 \sigma_i^2}$$
as a ratio for measuring diversity:  the lower the better.  It's similar to [Goetzmann & Kumar's Normalized portfolio variance](ftp://economia.unica.it/mattana/Modelli_Mercati_Finanziari/Slides/Lecture_2/CRAA.pdf) which @jaamor mentioned in his answer, but makes the denominator more relevant to the portfolio you're trying to measure (a lot of information is lost in a straight average $\bar{\sigma}$ of the $\sigma_i$'s).

**Edit:**  I think it makes even more sense to scale the denominator somehow, so portfolios with low numbers of stocks don't get a misleadingly bad score (or high numbers of stocks good scores).  Maybe divide by $\sum w_i^2$ or multiply by the number of stocks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the measure used by lebelinoz above is that the denominator, which is the square of the standard deviation of the hypothetical portfolio of the same assets  wherein the cross-correlations between the assets are all zero, is not necessarily greater than the numerator for all possible values of the cross-correlations.

A better quantity to use in the denominator is the square of the standard deviation of   the hypothetical portfolio of the same assets wherein the cross-correlations between the assets are all one. In that case it can be guaranteed that the ratio is always between zero and one.