# Diversification investment metric for a FI portfolio

Tags: portfolio-management, risk-management, performance-evaluation

What is a good investment metric to reward diversification within a portfolio. Suppose we have a fixed income universe and prefer stable currency, mid yield and mid tenors. Our stressed spread var covar matrix suggests that we have correlation factor amongst each  currency & fixed income class.

A simple metric would be weighted-portfolio for correlation
Possibly the HHI Herfindahl index weights

This is in the context of Solvency II but would apply much more broadly. Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: Linking in: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/what-to-use-as-portfolio-diversification-measure?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This extends to not just FI but multi asset class (MAC) as well. You can use a linear MAC factor model to compute specific\unsystematic risk.

Here's are several examples of such a model:

- https://www.msci.com/documents/1296102/5025433/PRESENTATION_FixedIncomeRoadshow.pdf
- https://www.jpmorgan.com/jpmpdf/1158651692009.pdf

You would compute specific risk the same way you normally would: [How to calculate unsystematic risk?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2205/how-to-calculate-unsystematic-risk)

Comment: The second link seems to be broken. I would appreciate if you could post a working link.

Comment: @AK88 thanks, second link should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Also intrested in this question. A more qualitative approch is presented [here](https://am.jpmorgan.com/blob-gim/1383280096921/83456/II-FIXINC-ALL.pdf).

Can you tell how did you get your variance-covariance matrix? Did you use daily price changes?

Somebody suggested using VaR if you have multi-currency FI portfolio. So you'd have VaR measures for specific bonds and for overall portfolio. And from there maybe you be able to see the difersification effect?

Comment: Generally a comparison (i.e. ratio) of the overall risk(s) of the portfolio to the average risk(s) of the securities within it can be used as a measure of diversification. "Risk" can be std. dev, VaR, other... . See "diversification ratio".

Comment: Thanks, not looking to diversify risk (e.g. on a variance based approach) but reward broad allocation.

Comment: @ AK88 covar matrix on monthly